# Making a multi-tenant application on flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a multi-tenant application using Flask, I have been following this guide, I am using Postgres sql for the database:

https://medium.com/@smirnov.am/multitenancy-with-flask-6f5375a34f55

So my point of confusion is that when I try to redirect to the specified url for I keep getting a internal server error, when I look at the logs this is what I get:

`TypeError: index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'organization_name'`

While following the guide I am going the same exact steps as he is doing, I am just not able to get the final output to show that it does work.

This is how I am structuring my app.route

```py
@app.route("/<organization_name>/users")
def index(organization__name):
    organization_session = get_organization_session(organization__name)
    if not organization_session:
        print(404)
    users = organization_session.query(Organization).all()
    return jsonify({organization__name: [i.username for i in users]})
```

And this is how I am setting my multi-tenant set up:

```py
DB_URI = my postgres uri 

# Manages the the multiple dbs for the organization

@simple_cache
def get_known_organizations():
    organizations = Organization.query.all()
    return [o.name for o in organizations]


def prepare_bind(organization):
    if organization not in current_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS']:
        current_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'][organization] = DB_URI.format(organization)
    return current_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'][organization]


def get_organization_session(organization):
    if organization not in get_known_organizations():
        return None
    prepare_bind(organization)
    engine = db.get_engine(current_app, bind=organization)
    session_maker = db.sessionmaker()
    session_maker.configure(bind=engine)
    sesh = session_maker()
    return sesh
```

Any help would be great appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your route `organization_name` has 1 underscore and in your function definition is has 2 `organization__name`. Both must match for your route to route correctly.

Comment: Well spotted @Zweep